# Scala way of coding

Tags: scala

I am moving from C / C++to Scala, and following is my code -

```
something match {
    case one: {
        if (some_list.nonEmpty) {
            if (some_list size == 1 && some_list contains == something)
                fill a form(use something in a certain way)
            else if (some_list size == 1 && some_list contains == soemthing_else)
                fill a form(use something_else in a certain way)
            else {
                if (some_var.nonEmpty) {
                    fill a form(use some_var)
                } else {
                    fill a form(without using some_var)
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (another_var has certain value || another_var has certain value 2) {
                fill a form(using another_var)
            } else {
                fill a form(without using another_var)
            }
        } //if (some_list.nonEmpty) ends
    } // case ends


    case two: one liner code

    case _: one liner code

} //match ends
```

Looking
for guidance to write it in a nice scala way using its features and strengths.
Thank you

Comment: `case two: one liner code`; _"Looking for guidance to write **it**"_: are we supposed to guess what "**it**" is supposed to be? ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

I am making a few assumptions to make this work:

```
trait cases

case object one extends cases
case object two extends cases
case object three extends cases
case object four extends cases

val someList: List[cases] = List(one, two)

val something: cases = one
val somethingElse: cases = two
val someVar: Option[String] = Option("someVar")
val someOtherVar: Option[String] = Option("someOtherVar")
val anotherVar: Option[String] = Option("anotherVar")
```

Following is a simplified version of your code using the above:

```
something match {
  case `one` => 
    someList match {
      case head :: Nil if(head == something) => println("one")
      case head :: Nil if(head == somethingElse) => println("two")
      case head :: tail if(someVar.nonEmpty) => println("someVar")
      case head :: tail if(someOtherVar.nonEmpty) => println("someOtherVar")
      case head :: tail => println("not using someOtherVar")
      case Nil if(anotherVar.nonEmpty) => println("anotherVar")
      case Nil => println("not using anotherVar")
    }
  case `two` => println("two")
  case _ => println("rest")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Johny. Went on similar lines after your inputs, and it looks better